# How can I debug an Adobe AIR application on Linux with ADL?

Tags: linux, air

I have a **very** simple Adobe AIR (HTML + JavaScript) application that I wrote a few months ago. I was using Ubuntu 9.x and the Adobe AIR SDK. I got the source from github today to pick it back up (hadn't been able to work on it for quite some time). I setup a new Ubuntu VM and downloaded the Adobe AIR SDK for Linux. When I tried to run ADL I received a "No such file exists" error.

**Actual Error:**

> max@RoR-Dev:~/src/OpenFlame$ /home/max/air/bin/adl
>
> bash: /home/max/air/bin/adl: No such file or directory

The only difference I can think of is that I'm running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu now instead of 32 bit. Is it not possible to debug Adobe AIR apps on 64 bit Linux? Am I doing something wrong? Is there something I can install to make it work? (I'm not a Linux or AIR expert by any means)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It figures. After hours of searching, I post a question. Within 10 minutes of posting the question, I find the answer!

Thanks to http://maketecheasier.com/run-32-bit-apps-in-64-bit-linux/2009/08/10/ I realized I could install the 32 bit libraries to make it work:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Very frustrating until I figurd it out.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is your mistake:

```
./home/max/air/bin/adl
```

That says to run the program `adl` located in `/home/max/src/OpenFlame/home/max/air/bin/adl`. (With the assumption that your home directory, `~`, is `/home/max`.)

The leading `.` says "start the search in the current working directory".

Try `/home/max/air/bin/adl` or `~/air/bin/adl`.

If you get sick of typing these, you can add `~/air/bin/` to your `PATH`: edit `~/.profile` and add near the end:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/air/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/air/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

(Don't forget to `source ~/.profile` or restart your shell.)

Then you should be able to run `adl` without adornment and have it start right up.

Comment: That was just one of the many things I tried when trying to make it work. I posted what solved my problem. But thank you for the detailed answer, and I will use your path suggestion.